# Manuel bleed screw won’t turn off sprinkler valve

Tags: sprinkler-system

I had the sprinkler system revised in May 2019.  The installers replaced both valves with Lawn Genie 3/4” valves.  About 6 months later, I replaced a sprinkler head (1/4 circle to 1/2).  I turned on the water valve manually using the bleed screw, as shown to me by the installers.  When I tried to turn off the water by closing the bleed screw, the sprinklers continued to run.  I had to turn off the water at the pipe.  The installers came back, and replaced the valve with a new 1.
Yesterday, I turned on the new valve using the bleed screw. I was testing a sprinkler head that seems to not be working.  Not knowing/ remembering which valve belongs to which station, I started with the new 1.  Guess what?  The water won’t shut off - again.

How do I fix this situation? I am a DYIer, and would prefer to fix this myself.  I just need guidance. Does the valve have to be replaced, again? Or is there a fix?
Right now, I have to manually water the entire back yard with a regular sprinkler, because with the water valve stuck open, the other station doesn’t have enough water pressure to even lift the heads.

The valve top reads at the very top 54000. But I don’t know what that is.  It is a 3/4” valve from Lawn Genie, 150 PSI max. 110°F H2O max

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some junk has gotten into the valve?

When turning off the bleed valve it takes maybe 20 seconds before valve turns off. Also, look at the solonoid (the thing with two wires on it). Sometimes it can be unscrewed as well (like bleed valve). So make sure solonoid is screwed in well. Then look for water leaking anywhere around valve, you may have to dry it with cloth to see.

Answer (score -1):

Hello Polypipe Wrangler,

I knew it would take time for the water to shut off after closing the bleed screw.  But 2, 3, 10 mins later - nope.

However - you gave me an idea, so I took the top off that valve.  I didn’t see anything wrong. (Darn)  I was expecting to maybe see debris preventing the bleed screw going all the way in.  So I put the cap back on, turned the water back on, and tried the bleed screw again.  This time it shut off like it should.  No clue what was wrong (still) but if that’s all it takes to “fix” it, I am happy(er).

Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Glad you were able to get the bleed screw to behave!  By the way, it looks like you created two accounts it seems, see [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them so you can use the site fully

Comment: The best way to say "thank you" is to click the up arrow next to any answer(s) that helped you, and click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_ (even if it's your own).